# Get CPU Frame time with Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, gpu, cpu

I'd like to create a system to change the quality of the graphics of my iOS application according to the power of the device. I already succeeded to get the FPS of the application in runtime, but I would like to push the thing further, in particular by getting the frame time of the CPU and the GPU.

I already managed to get the CPU usage percentage thanks to the [SystemKit](https://github.com/beltex/SystemKit) library, but the information returned is not very useful for the use I want to make of it.

Would you know the solutions to get such information?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code to get the percentage of use in Swift 5 :

```
public mutating func usageCPU() -> (system: Double, user: Double, idle: Double, nice: Double) {
        let load = System.hostCPULoadInfo()
        
        let userDiff = Double(load.cpu_ticks.0 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.0)
        let sysDiff  = Double(load.cpu_ticks.1 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.1)
        let idleDiff = Double(load.cpu_ticks.2 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.2)
        let niceDiff = Double(load.cpu_ticks.3 - loadPrevious.cpu_ticks.3)
        
        let totalTicks = sysDiff + userDiff + niceDiff + idleDiff
        
        let sys  = sysDiff  / totalTicks * 100.0
        let user = userDiff / totalTicks * 100.0
        let idle = idleDiff / totalTicks * 100.0
        let nice = niceDiff / totalTicks * 100.0
        
        loadPrevious = load
        
        return (sys, user, idle, nice)
}


fileprivate static func hostCPULoadInfo() -> host_cpu_load_info {
        var size = HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO_COUNT
        let hostInfo = host_cpu_load_info_t.allocate(capacity: 1)
        
        let result = hostInfo.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: Int(size)) {
            host_statistics(machHost, HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO, $0, &size)
        }
        
        let data = hostInfo.move()
        hostInfo.deallocate()
        
        #if DEBUG
            if result != KERN_SUCCESS {
                print("ERROR - \(#file):\(#function) - kern_result_t = "
                        + "\(result)")
            }
        #endif

        return data
}
```

Edit : Even though it is noted that the package only works for macOS, the code above works well for iOS and macOS.

Comment: iOS won't allow you to access CPU/RAM data. It is sensitive information.
This lib https://github.com/beltex/SystemKit is built for MacOS, not iOS.